# reuse a widget in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a label widget and im trying to add this widget to the multiple cells in the flex table but the widget is appearing only in the first cell. Is it possible to reuse a widget in gwt?? how?

```
Label l1=new Label("USER") ;
tweetFlexTable.setWidget(0,0,l1);
tweetFlexTable.setWidget(0,1,l1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every widget can only have one parent.

So you have to create as many widgets as you have cells, like this:

```
Label l1=new Label("USER") ;
tweetFlexTable.setWidget(0,0,l1);
Label l2=new Label("dunno") ;
tweetFlexTable.setWidget(0,1,l2);
```

Comment: I have a followup question do you consider every cell as a widget? because even if you reuse a cell in multiple cells the parent remains the same that is flex table!!

Comment: I dont`t really get your question. Are you talking about the CellTable from GWT?

Comment: ya!! im talking about the flextable in gwt!! in your answer you have mentioned that every widget can have only one parent. by reusing a label in multiple cells of a flex table the parent of the label still remains the same right?

Comment: but if you add it to another cell behind the scenes GWT removes it from the other cell.